# Replacing new/delete with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The ultimate idea here is prevent missing `delete` when an object is created with `new` which AFAIK do not have implicit lifetime.

original code

```
A* getA(...)
{
    return new A(...);
}

int func(...)
{
    auto x = getA(...);
    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

My try:

```
A* getA(...)
{
    return shared_ptr<A>(new A(...)).get();
}

int func(...)
{
    auto x = getA(...);
    return 0;
}
```

- Is this a good approach?
- When will `shared_ptr` end its lifetime? (Assuming that func(...) is a whole thread)
- When will `shared_ptr` end its lifetime? (Assuming that func(...) is called in a infinite looped thread)

Comment: Not a good approach, as you still return the raw non-owning pointer. And since the smart pointer will delete the object, the returned pointer will also be invalid. You must return the `std::shared_ptr` object.

Comment: The lifetime ends when the `shared_ptr` is destroyed, immediately before the `getA` function returns the pointer value. The pointer is useless in `func` because the object was destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two smart pointers, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. They model ownership of memory with different semantics. When there is only a single owner, then you should use `unique_ptr`, which is the case of most scenarios. `shared_ptr` does not seem the right choice for you here.

`getA()` could return a raw pointer. The idea is to wrap it with a smart pointer so that you don't have to manage it's lifetime explicitly.

```cpp
A* getA()
{
    return new A();
}

void takeA(A*)
{
}

int func()
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> ptr = getA();

   takeA(ptr.get());
}
```

Or, your `getA()` could return a smart pointer.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<A> getA()
{
    return std::make_unique<A>();
}
```

To answer your last question:

- `std::unique_ptr` lifetime ends when the smart pointer object goes out of scope. Since there is a single owner, at that point, the managed raw object is deleted.
- `std::shared_ptr` lifetime ends when the smart pointer object goes out of scope. Since there are multiple owners, when the last one is destroyed, the managed raw object is deleted. For this purpose, the `shared_ptr` is using a control block, allocated on the heap, towards which all instances that share the same object point. This control block has a counter, incremented when a new shared pointer pointing to the same object is created, and decremented when it is destroyed. When this counter reaches 0, the raw object is destroyed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use `new`/`delete` _anywhere_ in code. You can return smart pointer object from functions, so there is no need to call `new` at all.

Comment: so as you state, a function which return `A*` can also return `shared_ptr<A*>` ? and a function that return `shared_ptr<A*>` can aldo return `A*`?

Comment: @sklott I said "could" not "should". Besides, `getA()` could be an old function one cannot change. My point was to show how to take ownership of raw pointers using a smart pointer. But apart from that I won't disagree with you.

Comment: @Silver keep in mind it's `shared_ptr<A>` and not `shared_ptr<A*>`. What I am saying is that you could return either a raw pointer or a smart pointer. However, your function would have different semantics. By returning a smart pointer you are forcing the clients of that function to also use smart pointers to handle the return value. If you use a raw pointer then you have the choice of raw pointers or smart pointers. You should use smart pointers in general. Raw pointers should be left mostly for legacy APIs that you cannot change.

Answer (score 2):

No, not only is this not a good approach, it is wrong and is undefined behavior.

`shared_ptr` takes ownership of a pointer. The whole purpose of a `shared_ptr` is to ***use it instead of a pointer***, and when the `shared_ptr` goes away the underlying pointer gets automatically deleted.

```
 return shared_ptr<A>(new A(...)).get();
```

The following sequence of events happens here:

1. An instance of `A` is `new`ed.
2. `shared_ptr` gets constructed and takes ownership of the pointer to `A`.
3. The underlying pointer gets retrieved from the `shared_ptr` for the purpose of getting `return`ed.
4. The `shared_ptr` gets destroyed. It was only a temporary object. Its destructor then automatically `delete`s the underlying pointer.
5. You are left holding a bag to a deleted object, that got returned. Any further use of it is undefined behavior.

This should be, simply:

```
shared_ptr<A> getA(...)
{
    return shared_ptr<A>(new A(...));
}

int func(...)
{
    auto x = getA(...);
    return 0;
}
```

For all intents and purposes `x` is your smart pointer in your `func`. `x->something()` calls its `something` method, etc... When `func()` returns, it gets destroyed and the underlying pointer gets automatically `delete`d (unless, of course, a copy of it is saved somewhere, or gets passed to another function that stashes it away in some hidey-hole, etc...).

Comment: `std::make_shared` might avoid the `new` usage. `std::unique_ptr` seems a better replacement.